# Nginx поддомены с регулярным выражением

Tags: nginx, регулярные-выражения

Привет!

У меня есть вот такой конфиг:

```
server {
   listen           0.0.0.0:80;
   server_name      user.domain.ru *.user.domain.ru;

   charset          utf-8;
   root             /var/www/user.domain.ru/$subdomain;
   set              $subdomain "www";

   if ($host ~* ^([a-z0-9]+)\.user\.domain\.ru$) {
        set         $subdomain $1;
   }

   location / {
        autoindex   on;
        index       index.html index.htm;
   }
}
```

Благодаря ему некий **user** может делать любые поддомены.  
Хочу, чтобы у поддоменов тоже можно было делать поддомены, но чтобы они вели на родительский поддомен.

Т.е.: **test.site.user.domain.ru** ведёт на **site.user.domain.ru**

У меня проблема с регуляркой, никак не могу её придумать. Думаю, нужно как-то вот так:

```
[[\w\d]+\.]*([\w\d]+)\.user\.domain\.ru
```

(посмотреть тут: https://www.regex101.com/r/sE7pM6/2 )

Но не работает. :с

Answer (score 0, accepted):

То есть тебе нужно, чтобы в `$1` попало site? Ну, твоя регулярка находит то, что тебе нужно, правда, ужасно кривая. Такое подойдет?

```
.*?(\w+)\.user\.domain\.ru
```